# Setting Text View to be Int rather than String? Swift

Tags: swift, textview

I have a text view for the user to input an Int.

I am having an issue with saving the result into an Int variable as it default thinks its a string.

What would be the best solution to force the output as an Int? I am using a numerical only keyboard so the user cannot enter strings

code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userExerciseWeight: UITextField!
var userExerciseWeightSet = Int()

            if let userExerciseWeightSet = Int(self.userExerciseWeight.text!) {
    }
```

Comment: where is your tested code?

Comment: Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated the OP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `if let` construct for this. `textView` always will be string. all you need to do is convert `textView` text to `Int`.

```
 if let intText = Int(self.textView.text) {
     print(intText)
 }
```

Comment: I have updated the OP using this code method, does it seem correct?

Comment: you don't need to write this line var userExerciseWeightSet = Int(). because userExerciseWeightSet is creating two times.

Comment: so why wouldnt i use var userExerciseWeightSet = Int(self.userExerciseWeight.text!) as that would set the variable as an Int from the text box text? Or am i missing something. Also is this best situated in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: you can use this var userExerciseWeightSet = Int(self.userExerciseWeight.text!). in this case if the textview text is not converted to int  it will give you nil. so it's better to use if let construct. and it depends on your requirement where should you situated.

Comment: when setting it as the var i get the error "Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> ExerciseEditorController' has no member 'userExerciseWeight'". If i used your answers method where would i situate it? the requirement is literally just a conversion on the IBOutlet so i can assign the value to my core data entity

Comment: No no. you can't define it  outside the function. i mean it depends if you have any button on uiview and you  want it on button tap you can create button action and place this code there. and show your class code.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an issue with saving the result into an Int variable as it default thinks its a string.

Text view is a view, not a model. What it displays is always a string. When the string happens to represent an `Int`, your code is responsible for converting `Int` to `String` when setting the initial value, and then for converting `String` back to `Int` when reading the value back from the view.

```
if let intVal = Int(textView.text) {
    ... intVal from text is valid
} else {
    ... text does not represent an int - e.g. it's empty
}
```

The same approach applies to displaying and reading values of other types: your program is responsible for formatting and parsing the data into an appropriate type.